# Firebug script window changes scripts

Tags: firebug

I'm debugging some JS code with firebug in firefox, and I have two scripts in my page.  One is my own, the other is the kineticJS library.  However while I'm trying to set a breakpoint in my script, the script window keeps changing to the kineticJS script, making it very difficult to set break points.  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should ensure you have the latest Firebug release, which is currently [1.9.2](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/?page=1#version-1.9.2) (stable) or [1.10b1](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/?page=1#version-1.10.0b1) (beta).

If the problem is appearing within the 1.10b1 version and you have a proper [test case](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Creating_a_Test_Case), then you should create an issue in the [Firebug issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list).